# Wrapping of elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an input xml file that have multiple `<b>` elements, i have to wrap all `<b>` that are appearing continuously. i have written an xsl for this. it is better way to do this? also there are extra space generated during transformation after wrapping elements.

**Sample Input XML**

```
<chap>
<p><b>The</b> <b>Attorney</b> General <b>(Fees)</b><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b> Determination 2012 No 110 commenced on 1 <b>July</b> <b>2012</b> <b>and</b> was repealed on <b>1</b> <b>July</b> <b>2013</b>. The Determination is yet to be amended by:</p>
</chap>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:guru="Self"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::b]]
         |b[preceding-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space(.) = '']][preceding-sibling::node()[2][self::b]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::b]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="guru:wrap(following-sibling::node()[1], '')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space(.) = '']/following-sibling::node()[1][self::b]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="guru:wrap(following-sibling::node()[2], following-sibling::node()[1])"/>
            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="guru:wrap">
        <xsl:param name="b_data"/>
        <xsl:param name="space"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$space"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$b_data"/>
        <xsl:if test="$b_data/following-sibling::node()[1][self::b]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="guru:wrap($b_data/following-sibling::node()[1], '')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$b_data/following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space(.) = '']/following-sibling::node()[1][self::b]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="guru:wrap($b_data/following-sibling::node()[2], $b_data/following-sibling::node()[1])"/>
        </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<chap>
    <p><b>The Attorney</b>  General <b>(Fees)abc</b> Determination 2012 No 110 commenced on 1 <b>July 2012 and</b>   was repealed on <b>1 July 2013</b>  . The Determination is yet to be amended by:</p>
</chap>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<chap>
    <p><b>The Attorney</b> General <b>(Fees)abc</b> Determination 2012 No 110 commenced on 1 <b>July 2012 and</b> was repealed on <b>1 July 2013</b>. The Determination is yet to be amended by:</p>
</chap>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would think that merging `<b>(Fees)</b><b>a</b><b>b</b><b>c</b>` is easily done with using `for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::b)"`. For `<b>July</b> <b>2012</b> <b>and</b>` you need to explain a bit what are the rules, any text with white space in between or only text with a single space in between allows merging these `b` elements?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, there should be single space between `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `for-each-group group-adjacent="self::b or self::text()[. = ' ']"`:

```
  <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::b or self::text()[. = ' ']">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                      <b>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node() | current-group()[self::text()]"/>
                      </b>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>                  
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHU/1 shows the result, it uses XSLT 3 but for XSLT 2 you simply have to remove the `xsl:mode` and keep the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you have in your code.